# Troubleshooting a "this device cannot start. (code 10)" error

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a USB stick that, once inserted into my Windows 7 computer, gives this error and cannot be used. It works normally on other computers (Linux and Windows 7); other USB sticks work normally on the computer in question.

I have tried to:

- disable and reenable the device
- uninstall and reinstall drivers (allowing Windows to fetch them automatically)
- format the USB on another computer (also Windows 7)
- plug it on a different USB port

Nothing has helped so far. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Try this solution from Microsoft....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17614/automatically-diagnose-and-fix-windows-usb-problems

Comment: Other solution is to enter device manager and uninstall all usb hubs and root hub entries, then click the "scan for hardware changes" button to reinstall drivers.

Comment: Also see this...http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-usb-drive-this-device-cannot-start-code/3021c2c3-f595-4a9d-afc6-bbc6d9b69bc9?auth=1

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've already tried the Microsoft "solutions" (which rarely are), to no avail. I'm reluctant to uninstall all usb hubs, I have many devices connected. If there is no other solution (not requiring uninstalling all usb hubs), then I guess I'll have to accept I can't use this stick on this computer anymore.

Comment: This usually solves usb issues, I do it all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, I came across something simple that helped ([source](https://mspoweruser.com/how-to-fix-a-usb-drive-fragmented-into-separate-partitions/)) so I'm posting it in case it might help others.

(It goes without saying that i) make sure you select the right disk, because ii) everything in that disk will be deleted)

1. Run diskpart.exe
2. Type ‘list disk’ to see all disks listed. It should show all your connected hard drives with an associated number. Make a note of your flash drive number, then type ‘select disk [drive number goes here]’.
3. Enter in ‘clean’, then ‘create partition primary’.
4. format your drive by entering in the command ‘format fs=fat32 quick’
5. Type  ‘active’, then ‘assign.’
6. Once you’re done, type 'exit' to finish your work. Once this is done, your flash drive should be restored to normal.